# Laptop won't suspend Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: suspend, 17.10, xps

Whenever I try to suspend my laptop (XPS 15 9550 running Ubuntu 17.10), the screen goes black for a few seconds and then shows the lock screen again. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you install properly Ubuntu? What's happen if you run Ubuntu via USB or CD like preview? Is work properly?

Comment: It's installed properly